# SQL Mirroring - Application not pointing to new Primary

Tags: sql-server, mirroring, connections

Im stuck with a connection string issue

this is my connection string.

`<add name="APP01" connectionString="Server=10.169.0.2; Failover Partner=10.166.0.2; Initial Catalog=DB2017; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

If I do sql server mirroring failover, the application is not connecting to new primary server. Still all the connections goes to old primary.

Comment: Is the application reconnecting after the failover, or does it just continue to try to use the existing connections that are failing?  The application needs to reconnect once the connection to the old primary is broken, and then it should connect to the new primary.

Comment: It's reconnecting to old primary.

Comment: What is database state at 10.166.0.2, after you fail-over? Are you able to connect database at mirror server? Have you synchronized all the credentials? Please check firewall settings at mirror server.

Comment: Logs are in sync. After failover the 10.166.0.2 is changed to primary. No firewalls.

Comment: please try ipconfig /flushdns at application server.